# Split pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes with equal numbers of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe `df` :

```
        a              b          c
0   0.897134    -0.356157   -0.396212
1   -2.357861   2.066570    -0.512687
2   -0.080665   0.719328    0.604294
3   -0.639392   -0.912989   -1.029892
4   -0.550007   -0.633733   -0.748733
5   -0.712962   -1.612912   -0.248270
6   -0.571474   1.310807    -0.271137
7   -0.228068   0.675771    0.433016
8   0.005606    -0.154633   0.985484
9   0.691329    -0.837302   -0.607225
10  -0.011909   -0.304162   0.422001
11  0.127570    0.956831    1.837523
12  -1.074771   0.379723    -1.889117
13  -1.449475   -0.799574   -0.878192
14  -1.029757   0.551023    2.519929
15  -1.001400   0.838614    -1.006977
16  0.677216    -0.403859   0.451338
17  0.221596    -0.323259   0.324158
18  -0.241935   -2.251687   -0.088494
19  -0.995426   0.665569    -2.228848
20  1.714709    -0.353391   0.671539
21  0.155050    1.136433    -0.005721
22  -0.502412   -0.610901   1.520165
23  -0.853906   0.648321    1.124464
24  1.149151    -0.187300   -0.412946
25  0.329229    -1.690569   -2.746895
26  0.165158    0.173424    0.896344
27  1.157766    0.525674    -1.279618
28  1.729730    -0.798158   0.644869
29  -0.107285   -1.290374   0.544023
```

that I need to split into multiple dataframes that will contain every 10 rows of `df` , and every small dataframe I will write to separate file. so  I decided create multilevel dataframe, and for this first assign the index to every 10 rows in my `df` with this method:

```
df['split'] = df['split'].apply(lambda x: np.searchsorted(df.iloc[::10], x, side='right')[0])
```

that throws out

```
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So, do you have an idea of how to fix it? Where is my method wrong?

But if you have another approach to split my dataframe into multiple dataframes every of which contains 10 rows of `df`, you are also welcome, cause this approach was just the first I thought about, but I'm not sure that it's the best one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want, your method looks over-complicated. A groupby using a scaled index as the grouping key would work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(100, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
groups = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//10)
for (frameno, frame) in groups:
    frame.to_csv("%s.csv" % frameno)
```

Comment: thanks @AlexW, it's exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: How to do the same in scala?

Comment: Should `/` be replaced by `//`? Otherwise each group contains only one row, as the indices remain unique.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to save slices of the dataframe in groups of ten rows:

```
df_dict = {n: df.iloc[n:n+10, :] 
           for n in range(0, len(df), 10)}

>>> df_dict.keys()
[0, 10, 20]

>>> df_dict[10]
           a         b         c
10 -0.011909 -0.304162  0.422001
11  0.127570  0.956831  1.837523
12 -1.074771  0.379723 -1.889117
13 -1.449475 -0.799574 -0.878192
14 -1.029757  0.551023  2.519929
15 -1.001400  0.838614 -1.006977
16  0.677216 -0.403859  0.451338
17  0.221596 -0.323259  0.324158
18 -0.241935 -2.251687 -0.088494
19 -0.995426  0.665569 -2.228848
```

Comment: This works for dataframes that don't have simple integer indexs too, thanks a lot!